# Problem with connecting to camera in Qt CPP

Tags: c++, qt, camera

I'm running a simple program in Qt creator to connecting to a camera. When I run the program, the following issue is reported:

Graph failed to connect filters -2147467259
[0x0] Failed to connect graph (The operation completed successfully.)

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?! Any solution would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what is that simple program? can you paste the code?

Comment: there is a workaround mentioned here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42909

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link you mentioned. But i didn't understand the exact way to solve the problem.

Here is the code i used to connect to a camera:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connected = false;
    camera = new QCamera();

    qDebug() << "Number of cameras found:" << QCameraInfo::availableCameras().count();

    QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
    foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, cameras)
    {
        qDebug() << "Camera info:" << cameraInfo.deviceName() << cameraInfo.description() << cameraInfo.position();
        ui->comboBox->addItem(cameraInfo.description());
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(!connected)
        connectCamera();
    else {
        camera->stop();
        viewfinder->deleteLater();
        ui->pushButton->setText("Connect");
        connected = false;
    }
}

void MainWindow::connectCamera()
{
    QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();

    foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, cameras)
    {
        qDebug() << cameraInfo.description() << ui->comboBox->currentText();
        if(cameraInfo.description()==ui->comboBox->currentText()) {
            camera = new QCamera(cameraInfo, this);
            viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
            camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);

            ui->horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(viewfinder);

            connected = true;
            ui->pushButton->setText("Disconnect");
            camera->start();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be an edit to the question, not an answer